# How to Marshall LLVMSharp Function

Tags: c#, delegates, llvm, marshalling

So teaching myself some compiler design using ANTLR4 & LLVMSharp. Trying to add 2 doubles with a marshal function and the application crashes in debug mode only (possible stack corruption?) IR generated for the example below. There is no issue when marshalling integers as the parameters.

```
define double @main(double %x, double %y) #0 {
entry:
  %tmp = fadd double %x, %y
  ret double %tmp
}
```

The error is shown below.

```
Managed Debugging Assistant 'FatalExecutionEngineError' 
The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error was at 0x737e17cf, on thread 0x299c. The error code is 0xc0000005. This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user marshalling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack.
```

Code for marshalling is shown below

```
LLVMBool success = new LLVMBool(0);
LLVMModuleRef module = LLVM.ModuleCreateWithName("LLVMSharpIntro");
LLVMTypeRef[] param_types = { LLVM.DoubleType(), LLVM.DoubleType() };
LLVMTypeRef ret_type = LLVM.FunctionType(LLVM.DoubleType(), param_types, false);
LLVMValueRef sum = LLVM.AddFunction(module, "main", ret_type);

LLVMBasicBlockRef entry = LLVM.AppendBasicBlock(sum, "entry");
LLVMBuilderRef builder = LLVM.CreateBuilder();
LLVM.PositionBuilderAtEnd(builder, entry);

LLVMValueRef tmp = LLVM.BuildFAdd(builder, LLVM.GetParam(sum, 0), LLVM.GetParam(sum, 1), "tmp");
LLVM.BuildRet(builder, tmp);

if(LLVM.VerifyModule(module,LLVMVerifierFailureAction.LLVMPrintMessageAction, out var error) != success)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Error: {error}");
}

LLVM.LinkInMCJIT();
LLVM.InitializeX86TargetMC();
LLVM.InitializeX86Target();
LLVM.InitializeX86TargetInfo();
LLVM.InitializeX86AsmParser();
LLVM.InitializeX86AsmPrinter();

LLVMMCJITCompilerOptions options = new LLVMMCJITCompilerOptions { NoFramePointerElim = 1 };
LLVM.InitializeMCJITCompilerOptions(options);
if (LLVM.CreateExecutionEngineForModule(out var engine, module, out error) != success)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Error: {error}");
}
LLVM.DumpModule(module);
var addMethod = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer<FloatingPoint>(LLVM.GetPointerToGlobal(engine, sum));
GC.KeepAlive(addMethod);

Console.WriteLine(addMethod(6.0, 2.0));
```

Edit: Solution found, you have to run the C# project in x64 cpu target even though it is targeting x86. Apparently the debugger flips out otherwise. Don't think there is actually anything incorrect in the code itself, just the unmanaged function seems to not be handled well by the debugger in those situations.